# Get the same results from SimpleXML as json_decode in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays, json, object

I'm attempting to load a config file as either XML or JSON. I know this is reinventing the wheel but I'm trying to get use to a couple of patterns I've never used.

My problem is that I can't not figure out a way to inform `SimpleXML_Load_File` that an element should be treated as an array and not object when the element only has 1 occurrence.

Consider the following JSON:

```
{
    "database" : 
    {
        "name" : "MyDB",
        "driver" : "MySQL",
        "table" : 
        [
            {
                "name" : "user",
                "engine" : "MyISAM",
                "column" : 
                [
                    {
                        "name" : "username",
                        "type" : "varchar",
                        "size" : "25"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "password",
                        "type" : "varchar",
                        "size" : "60"
                    }
                 ]
              }
          ]
      }
  }
```

And the related XML:

```
<config>
    <database>
        <name>MyDB</name>
        <driver>MySQL</driver>
        <table>
            <name>user</name>
            <engine>MyISAM</engine>
            <column>
                <name>username</name>
                <type>varchar</type>
                <size>25</size>
            </column>
            <column>
                <name>password</name>
                <type>varchar</type>
                <size>60</size>
            </column>
        </table>
    </database>
</config>
```

These configurations are the same with the exception of the `<config>` element - which I added due to the way `SimpleXML` handles the root level element.

With JSON you use `[ ]` to specify an array and `json_decode` will make the corresponding element an array of objects (such as `table`) - HOWEVER with XML there is no way to accomplish this as far as I can tell - and the result in this example with `SimpleXML_Load_File` is that `table` will be an object instead of the expected (by me) array of objects that is returned with `json_decode`

I'm feeling like I may have to do type-testing and conversions on the elements that should be arrays instead of objects, but I also feel like this could get really messy.

This is the relevant code used to load these files:

```
<?php $config_xml = simplexml_load_file( 'database.config.xml' ); ?>
<?php $config_json = json_decode( file_get_contents('database.config.json'), false ); ?>
```

Results:

`$config_xml->database->table` - object

`$config_json->database->table` - array of objects

Comment: It's not as simple as you might think it is. How SimpleXMLElement is turned into JSON and how you can modify that I have outlined in a three-part blog post starting here: [SimpleXML and JSON Encode in PHP – Part I](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-i/). If you read the first and second part you might be able to better understand the third part which shows extensively how to change JSON representation of the XML. However I'm not so sure if that what you try to do is possible in a general manner. Most likely ...

Comment: ... your code then contains "magic numbers" for the element names you want to have as an array.

Answer (score 1):

two things:

- to extend S Korolevs answer: there is no way to have an "anonymous" array in XML. In fact, strictly speaking, there are no arrays as such in XML, just elements that are only allowed (by schema or convention) to have special other elements as children. BTW, you will get the same issue with the columns
- SimpleXML is a strange beast, I find it notoriously hard to debug and examine (at least xdebug has some trouble to traverse into childnodes or even display attributes). 
  Important to note in your case is that a SimpleXML Element is always an object, never an array. It "just" implements the array access interface, so that you can fetch childnodes with `$element->children[0]`.

ok, a third thing or better a conclusion:

you are getting different config objects not so much because of the source structures, but because of the different parsers you use. `json_decode` returns an object of `stdClass`, `simplexml_load_file` returns an object of `SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: What both of you are saying makes sense. I do understand the constraints of the XML format for the current usage. Would you be willing to make a recommendation for a different parsing lib that might be able to use XSD as a guide? I guess the approach I might take is restructuring both outputs to conform to a single expected output. I was trying to keep it simple in hopes of being able to use the objects each created as is.

Comment: the DOMDocument class can validate against XML schemas, but I don't think it will structure the output (http://us2.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.schemavalidate.php). One idea for the restructuring: use `<tables>` with `<table` elements as "array" in the xml, and `tables` instead of `table` as key in the JSON, so that you can do `$object->tables[0]` in both cases. Another idea: take a look at ZendFramework 1's ini reader module, they have parser for xml and some other fomats

Answer (score 0):

Of course, in your XML **table** is representing an object. Array in XML is something like this:

```
<tables>
    <table>
            <name>user</name>
            <engine>MyISAM</engine>
            <column>
...
            </column>
            <column>
...
            </column>
     </table>
     <table>
     ...
     </table>
</tables>
```

So, **tables** is an array of **table** items. The issue I see is that structure of JSON and XML objects will be different in this case.

Comment: The first thing I tested was adding an empty `<table></table>` element and the results were what I was expecting. I'm trying to avoid having to always include an empty element-set. It would be nice to be able to use something like an XSD schema file to guide the resulting object.

Comment: Yes - the structure of the objects WILL be different - this is exact issue I'm trying to avoid or correct.